# Creating RPM Package to Copy File

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I want to create RPM to put .desktop file in /usr/share/applications and then run update-desktop-database command, I searched for a simple example to do that but couldn't find one, could someone give me a simple example or tutorial to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See:
https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Guidelines#Desktop_files

There is even link to documentatio how to handle icons and documented how to validate the results

Comment: Thank you very much, that is what I was looking for